# Permission to not disclose author's affiliation?

Tags: discussion, support, answers, how-to-answer, spam

I'm talking specifically about [this answer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/a/21835/27189) from the moderator Todd A. Jacobs.

In the end of the answer, there's a "See Also" section including many links to other answers from Todd A. Jacobs, without disclosing his affiliation.

Is this considered SPAM or we are allowed to share links without disclosing affiliation when those links are from this community or there's moderator exemption?

Comment: Links within the same site are IMHO unproblematic. Trying to drive traffic to an external site is what the disclosure requirement is supposed to discourage.

Comment: Shall we take that as a rule?

Comment: Probably wait for one of the regulars on this site to weigh in. I am broadly involved in volunteer spam prevention efforts across Stack Exchange but not a regular on this particular site.

Comment: Thank you @tripleee

Comment: It is very unclear how one should proceed, different people have different expectations of what SPAM really is. Just found the following answers https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/371756/5675325 and https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/58035/364217 which seem to be contradicting each other. I just followed the currently established rules but there's flexibility on top of them. Would be great to understand that flexibility for each community to know how to proceed.

Comment: There is a marked difference between those two. The first one covers answers of the type "the answer to your problem is this product or service (which I have an undisclosed stake in promoting)" and the second is "here is the answer to your question about some product or service; I happen to be the author or provider of that". So, lack of disclosure where disclosure is required vs voluntary disclosure where none is strictly required.

Comment: Tangentially, "spam" is not an acronym, and is usually spelled in lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [How to not be a spammer](https://pm.stackexchange.com/help/promotion), the affiliation disclousure is required when the author makes mention of their product, website, etc.

NOTE: In the above referred article "product" doesn't include the posts on the Stack Exchange network

Since all the links in the referred post point to posts author hosted in the Stack Exchange network, and more specifically in this site, it's not necessary that they do an affiliation disclousure in the referred answer.

Related

- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/289691)

Comment: Isn't an answer a "product" of the writer?

Comment: In this context (Stack Exchange network wide content policies) no

Comment: What makes you say that? Asking because if OP isn't the owner, why give that OP reputation?

Comment: I didn't say that the OP isn't the answer owner.

Comment: @TiagoMartinsPeres Answer edited. If you still need clarification, please post a new question describing your interpretation of the sources requiring affiliation disclousure, i.e. what do you understand by "product".

Comment: Nice, thanks Rubén!